# Replace part of Select Statement in Powershell

Tags: powershell, select, replace, powershell-3.0

I'm working with Powershell to get some information out of DHCP server.
I'm using this command to get the information i need.

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 10.132.56.0 | select IPAddress,ClientId,HostName | sort hostname | format-table
```

Results are as i expect:

> | IPAddress     | ClientId          | HostName  |
> |---------------|-------------------|-----------| | 10.132.56.121 |
> 40-83-de-2b-66-27 |           | | 10.132.56.101 | 40-83-de-2b-64-fb |
> | | 10.132.56.76  | 4c-c9-5e-6d-f2-30 | [Signage] |

I wih to remove the "-" from the ClientId.

I've tried the -replace "*",""
I've tried

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 10.132.56.0 | select IPAddress,$_.ClientId -replace "-","" ,HostName | sort hostname | format-table
*Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:1 char:75
+ Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 10.132.56.0 | select IPAddress,$_.ClientId -repla ...
+                                                                           ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand$_.ChildID.replace("-","")*
```

But i get different errors.

I wish i can do it on one line without storing variables of arrays.

Any help?
Maybe it's impossible, but i doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `-replace` operation in a *property expression*:

```
... Select IPAddress,{$_.ClientId -replace '-'},...
```

If you want the resulting property to retain the name `ClientId`, wrap the property expression in a hashtable (this is sometimes referred to as a *calculated property*):

```
... Select IPAddress,@{Name='ClientId';Expression={$_.ClientId -replace '-'}},...
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias.
I've seen the mistake i was making. I've tried the put the -replace in an expression but didn't work.
I've been Putting " " instead of ' '

Comment: @FrancescoCicciuzz it would have worked with either `"` or `'` - the problem is that PowerShell's parser can't distinguish between _parameters_ and _operators_ [in argument mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1) - the `{}` creates a lexical boundary that makes it unambiguous